# Is javascript filter library good for SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm currently working on a filter that can contain functionality such as search, sort, pagination, checkbox like in the following image.
[image]

For now, I use Laravel and trust every functionality to the query builder.For example : `->where()`, `pagination(10)`, `sortBy()`, `orderBy()`. But I'm afraid, This will make users uncomfortable because every time the user change filter values. I force the ajax to reload the page.

I  use ajax to load server-side rendered paginated product list page. Every time the input inside filter form gets changed. I submit the form and refresh the specific div.

With this method, I have to make some conditional because if I right-click the pagination link and open in new tab. It will show the page without CSS loaded. So I made conditional logic that prevent user to access the URL without accessing the main page.

```
if($request->get('paginated')!=true){ 
//I'm afraid this will block google crawler to get in. Because i block everyone when the link gets accessed without prerequisite parameter
return redirect()->to( route('shop-product',[ 'category' => $category, 'type' => $type ])); 
}
```

Is this a good practice? If it's not.

I want to use libraries like list.js, pagination.js, isotope but I doubt it. I think the javascript will ruin the SEO. Because the URL will not link to the specific information.

In my mind, I'm planning to load all the data in some variables like this `var data=@json($data)` and render the views using 1 of those libraries. There will be not any extra string in the URL.

Are those libraries good for SEO? should I use the library or keep the website in plain blade+php

(I'm still new in SEO kind of things)

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! We do not allow new users to link to their domain. I have edited your question. If anyone needs to see your link as written, they can simply review the edits to follow the link. Cheers!!

Comment: Pagination is worthless for SEO no matter how it is implemented.  See [this answer of mine](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/123588/14543).